# gradle using vm option jasypt private key is not working

Tags: java, spring, encryption, jvm, jasypt

I want to use db password with jasypt.

first, in application.yml, it is working writing jasypt.encryptor.password=myencrypt.

but I want use vm option.
so I use $ ./gradlew -Djasypt.encryptor.password=myencrypt bootRun

but it makes
Failed to bind preperties under spring.datasources.password to java.lang.string:
Reason: either 'jasypt.encryptor.password' or one of ['jasypt.encryptor.privatr-key-string', 'jasypt.encrytor.private-key-location'] must be provided for password-based or Asymmetric encryption

jasypt version 2.1.2 and 3.0.4 are same error type.
jdk 1.8

Comment: `gradlew` is a shell script; check its docs for how to apply Java properties. (You can also use the environment variable `JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
-Pjasypt.encryptor.password=myencrypt
```

in build.gradle

```
bootRun {
    systemProperty "jasypt.encryptor.password", findProperty("jasypt.encryptor.password")
}
```

with jasypt 2.1.2.

above 3.0.0, need something like `jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname`
because algorithm change